# Trying to restore data from MySQL Workebench 6.3 to MySQL Workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to move my data/tables/everything from a MySQL 6.3 CE Workbench to MySQL 8.0 CE.

When I just tried initally, I had and fixed this error - [Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336378/variable-sql-mode-cant-be-set-to-the-value-of-no-auto-create-user) .

Now I have a new error that I cannot figure out - ERROR 1359 (HY000) at line 1991: Trigger already exists.

I got this error trying to do Server->Data Import->Self Contained File into a completely empty database in MySQL Workbench 8.  The only changes I made to the self contained file were the removing the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER.  I also tried after running

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

in MySql.

Here's the exact dump code -

```
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `tab`.`history_mapinvoiceitems_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `history_mapinvoiceitems` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
set @lineitemid = new.lineitemid;
set @userIdInv = new.userIdinv;
END */;;
```

The very first line is the line that used to give me issues but since removing NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, is fine.  I also did a search to see if somehow this trigger was defined previously, but this line is literally the first occurrence of the word in the document.

Anyone else have this issue/fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a misunderstanding here: MySQL Workbench is a client tool, similar to the MySQL terminal or shell. It doesn't itself have any databases but connects to a MySQL server to query or update data (or manage the server).

**Hence there is no need (and you actually can't even do it) to move any MySQL data from WB 6.3 to WB 8.0.**

If your plan instead is to copy data from one MySQL server (say, an old 5.5 installation) to a newer one (say, 8.0) then use MySQL Workbench 8 to migrate the data. Use the Migration Wizard for that, reachable from the left sidebar on the homescreen.

Comment: We want to be able to use WB 8 instead of 6.3. I did miss a detail in that we are trying to set this a new MySQL server up on a new machine hence the data dump.  But you're saying if I just use 6.3 to Data Import to the new MySQL server, then load up 8.0 and connect, that should work right?

Comment: Yes, you can use either version of Workbench for that task, but I strongly recommend WB 8, if one of the participating servers is 8.0+.