# Import database dump with size of 20GB

Tags: mysql, dump

I have a mysql database dump with 25GB of size

i use mysql 8 to import this dump

```
[root@hotsing] mysql -V

mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

I run this command  `mysql -u root -p mydatabase < MySQLDump.sql`

During import, this error message is show and the operation is failed

```
ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 22715: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'
```

this is my sql mode

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

how i can resolve this , it is error from the dump or misconfiguration of mysql ? or the version of current mysql and the version of the database dump ?

thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable 'sql\_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO\_AUTO\_CREATE\_USER'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336378/variable-sql-mode-cant-be-set-to-the-value-of-no-auto-create-user)

Comment: Thank You ; i wish this article can help me , please don't close this topic

Comment: Does the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50721776/5981) suggesting removing `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` from the `SET sql_mode` lines in your MySQLDump.sql file not work? Please edit your question to show what happens when you try this?