# Restoring mysql 5.6 dump to mysql 8

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it safe to restore a dump taken from mysql 5.6 aws rds instance to mysql 8 aws rds instance? Is there any incompatibilities we should worry about?
Thank you.

Comment: *Is there any incompatibilities we should worry about?* Yes, they are. But nobody will give complete incompatibilities list. Find (and fix) them in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I faced  below problem when restoring  a dump from `MySQL 5.7.16` to `MySQL 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3`

> ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 45316: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to
> the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'

The solution that I used ;

> sed -i 's/NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER//' my_file.sql

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336378/variable-sql-mode-cant-be-set-to-the-value-of-no-auto-create-user)

Maybe you might face another problem

You should read [Server and Status Variables and Options Added, Deprecated, or Removed in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/added-deprecated-removed.html)